# Need to read some (or all) columns as.character when combining multiple .csv files with tidyr functions

Tags: r, csv, tidyr, purrr, rbind

I'm reading many large .csv files with identical column names and row-binding them using the following code (as suggested at https://serialmentor.com/blog/2016/6/13/reading-and-combining-many-tidy-data-files-in-R):

```
require(readr)  # for read_csv()
require(purrr)  # for map(), reduce()

# find all file names ending in .csv 
files <- dir(pattern = "*.csv")
files

data <- files %>%
  map(read_csv) %>%    # read in all the files individually, using
                   # the function read_csv() from the readr package
  reduce(rbind)        # reduce with rbind into one dataframe
data
```

However, my data has one column that needs to be read in as.character, because it has entries of number strings separated by ",", and otherwise read_csv turns that column into numeric without the commas.

How can I

1.) Specify to read in just the one column (preferably by name) as.character?

or

2.) Simply read in all columns as.character?

This second option is not ideal, since then I have to change many columns back to numeric.

I tried using:

```
col_types = cols(.default = "c")
```

as discussed at https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/148 and https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/292.

My approach was this:

```
data <- files %>%
   map(read_csv( col_types = cols(.default = "c" ))) %>%
   reduce(rbind)   
data
```

However, this doesn't work because then read_csv() wants an 'x' input (i.e. .csv file path). It throws this error:

```
Error in read_delimited(file, tokenizer, col_names = col_names, col_types = col_types,  : 
  argument "file" is missing, with no default
```

Comment: Try `map(~read_csv(., col_types = cols(.default = "c" )))` You need to more formally pass the filename from `map()` to `read_csv`

Comment: I'd also add you can use map_df and drop the reduce. purr allows for setting your output explicitly. it saves a couple of lines. also, if your column names are consistent you can feed that specific column as character-based in your read_csv() call

Comment: @elmuertefurioso How would I explicitly specify as.character just by the column name? E.g. let's say the column name is "bad_scans".

Comment: using the read_csv() syntax would like something like: read_csv(., col_types = cols(bad_scans = "c"). Then readr would determine the other coumn types in its normal fashion.

Comment: @elmuertefurioso When I try `map(~read_csv(., col_types = cols(.default = "c" )))` I get the warning message `Error: Can't convert a 'tbl_df' object to function
Call 'rlang::last_error()' to see a backtrace` This happens whether I specify for a specific column as you suggest, or all columns as @MrFlick suggested.

Comment: okay, this looks an error of reading the files in the first place. i would get your list of file paths using list.files() and try a map variation like : map_df(list_of_paths, read_csv). if that works, then you can add the col_types argument as an additional arg like map_df(list_of_paths, read_csv, col_types = cols(...))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nine (or other number) columns with identical column names for each .csv file, only two columns (in this case "start_scan" and "end_scan") to be read as numeric, all the others as character:

```
files <- dir(pattern = "*.csv")

metadata <- files %>%
  map_df(~read_csv(., col_types = cols(.default = "c", 
    scan_end = "n", scan_start = "n") ))
```